# Efficient way to apply function to all pairs of row (or column)

Tags: r, matrix, function

Given a matrix (can be very big dimension), how can I efficiently compute a result matrix `d`, with each value defined as `d[i,j] = fun(x[, c(i,j)])` for some given function `fun`

The following is an example

```
x = matrix(1:30, 5)
d = matrix(,ncol(x), ncol(x)) ## the output matrix
for(i in 1:ncol(x)) ## I use a for loop here, should find a more efficient way
for(j in 1:ncol(x)) 
d[i,j] = sum(apply(x[,c(i,j)], 1, min))
```

Comment: Are i and j always neighboring columns?

Comment: What if `x[,i]` does not exist, say if the number of rows is much larger than the number of columns?

Comment: No, they are all pairwise columns

Comment: The general solution is apply but there may be workarounds for particular functions.

Comment: You appear to be indexing into the columns of `x` using `i` and `j`, but `i` is explicitly a *row* index!  What sense does this make?  Could you supply a minimal reproducible example that illustrates your intentions?

Comment: You would use `combn` function in base R. This gives the pairwise columns` eg: `combn(data.frame(x),2,fun)`. Where fun is the specified function

Comment: @whuber `i` is explicity a `column` index. look at the for-loop above.

Comment: @Onyambu That is true now, but it wasn't the case in the original, which I was still reading when I wrote that comment: check the edit history.  Concerning your other comments, please note that using `combn` does not create the result indicated by the two for loops.

Comment: @RuiBarradas look at the for-loop. `for(i in 1:ncol(x))` meaning `i` is the column index of `x`. According to the question, d should be a square matrix, since you will have `fun(x[, c(i,j)])` and `fun(x[, c(j,i)])` for all the columns. Thus the creation of `d` above is incorrect

Comment: @whuber use of combn does create the indicated results. Only that it will create the lower triangle of the matrix. eg: `combn( data.frame(x),2,function(m)sum(do.call(pmin,m)))`

Comment: @Onyambu `combn` omits the diagonal.  By using it you also assume the function `fun` is commutative which--although suggested by the example--was not stated.

Comment: @whuber. I agree with that. In this case we need more information

Answer (score 2):

**Think about where the work happens.**

You want to examine all pairs of columns of `x`.  For each pair, you are creating an n by 2 matrix and applying some function to that.  In many cases, such as the one illustrated, some of the effort will go into moving the data around to pick out those columns and create those new matrices.  (The loop overhead is minimal.)  The rest of the effort will go into applying the function.  `R` provides opportunities to improve the speed of both:

1. When data are only read and not modified by a function, `R` has some automatic built-in optimizations to reference them with pointers rather than making full copies.
2. Some functions are inherently vectorized when applied to simple (one-dimensional) arrays but may be slower when invoked with the `apply*` functions or by looping.

**These give us some guidance concerning where to look when improving the speed of an array operation.**  The details depend on what `fun` does, so let's consider the example in the question: it computes the smaller of each row of the n by 2 array and sums those results.  `R` supports a built-in, vectorized (very fast) function, `pmin`, to compute the row minima.  That suggests the following solution:

```
n <- 50
m <- 100
x <- matrix(runif(n*m), n)
system.time({
  y <- matrix(NA_real_, NCOL(x), NCOL(x))
  for (i in seq_len(NCOL(y)))
    for (j in seq_len(NCOL(y)))
     y[i,j] <- sum(pmin(x[, i], x[, j]))
})
```

In the best case we know the timing will eventually be linear in `n` and quadratic in `m`.  Here is an empirical study of the speedup afforded by this solution relative to the `sapply` method recommended in another answer in this thread.

[image: Figure: raster graphic of speedup as a function of m and n]

*This study was conducted using Microsoft R Open (3.5.1) on four Xeon cores.  For small `m`, the relative timings are uncertain because this solution takes almost no measurable time.  Note that the values shown are multiples, not percents: thus, for example, the typical multiple of 30+ for n=400 columns means this solution takes less than 1/30th of the time of the `sapply` solution.*

**The pattern is clear:** the vectorization of `pmin` achieves a great deal for large numbers of rows (`n`), while the underlying optimizations in `R` initially make a big difference for small numbers of columns (`m`) (less than 40 or so) but almost none for larger `m`.

**The lesson is that you should direct your efforts toward improving the timing of `fun` through vectorization and not worry about loop overhead.**

Answer (score 1):

A `sapply` loop will be slightly faster

```
sapply(1:NCOL(x), function(i) sapply(1:NCOL(x), function(j){
    sum(apply(x[, c(i, j)], 1, min))
}))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   15   15   15   15   15   15
#[2,]   15   40   40   40   40   40
#[3,]   15   40   65   65   65   65
#[4,]   15   40   65   90   90   90
#[5,]   15   40   65   90  115  115
#[6,]   15   40   65   90  115  140
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution that only computes half of the values. This is because the way the two `for` loops are coded, the result matrix is symmetric.
I have defined a function `fun` to be applied.

```
fun <- function(x, i, j) sum(apply(x[, c(i, j)], 1, min))

f1 <- function(x){
  d = matrix(NA, ncol(x), ncol(x))
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)){ ## I use a for loop here, should find a more efficient way
    for(j in 1:ncol(x)) 
      d[i, j] = fun(x, i, j)
  }
  d
}

f2 <- function(x){
  d = matrix(NA, ncol(x), ncol(x))
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    for(j in i:ncol(x)) d[i, j] = fun(x, i, j)
  }
  d[lower.tri(d)] <- t(d)[lower.tri(t(d))]
  d
}


library(microbenchmark)

n <- 1e3
x = matrix(1:n, 125)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(x),
  f2 = f2(x)
)
mb
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#   f1 14.117403 14.365764 15.297683 14.633804 15.202872 22.57475   100   b
#   f2  7.964885  8.113796  8.650553  8.252852  8.399395 17.33304   100  a
```

This is a median 43% time gain.

Comment: This assumes that the function `fun` is commutative which might not be the case.

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, I thought of that, but the example is commutative. Also, the *real* optimization would be to vectorize `fun`. In the question's example there is `matrixStats::rowMins`.